# Django admin filter widget in iOS

Tags: ios, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using the django admin's filter widget on my own forms page. However, I've noticed that iOS hijacks this widget, replacing it with its own native widget.

Is there anyway to prevent this override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that has been open for over two years:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14716

I think that until the bug gets fixed, you should either remove the widget for all devices or remove it for only iOS devices. I'll assume you prefer the latter. I thought of a way to do it, but it's very hacky. My idea is to monkey patch `django.contrib.admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple`. You would change the JavaScript generated by its `render` method so that rather than having the JavaScript immediately call the `addEvent` function, it would call it *only* if the user agent doesn't contain "iPad", "iPhone", or "iPod". You may also need to override the `updateSelectFilter` functions defined in these files:

1. django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/stacked.html
2. django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html

As I said, this solution is very hacky, but I'm not sure how any workaround to this problem could *not* be hacky.

Comment: Thanks! I also found the ticket, but thought maybe there was a solid workaround by now.